# Rails 5 remote form redirect to different pages using virtual attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, virtual-attribute

I have a `remote: true` form in my Rails 5 app and I'd like to redirect to different pages depending on when it's used.

I've tried adding a `:redirect_to` virtual attribute:

```
<%= a.input :redirect_to, as: :hidden, input_html: { 
    value: confirmation_orders_path
} %>
```

And modified my model to accept this virtual attribute:

```
attribute :redirect_to, :string
attr_accessor :redirect_to
```

But I still see `Unpermitted parameter: :redirect_to`.  What can I do to allow this param to pass?

Comment: Have you tried `params.require(:confirmation_orders).permit(:redirect_to)` in your controller?

Comment: I had it in the controller prior to adding the `attribute` to the model and it threw an error so I removed it.  I guess you need to have BOTH the model attribute AND and the controller permittance in order for it to work!

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: redirect_to does not seem to be a reserved word, but I would still try something that doesn't look like a ruby command. Also you have declared your attribute twice. I am not very used to `attribute` so I can't say which is better... but just remove `attribute :redirect_to, :string` and keep `attr_accessor :redirect_to` and see what happens

Comment: I believe `attribute :redirect_to, :string` is the Rails 5 way of doing it.

Comment: Also why not a `text_field` or `hidden_field`, `input` does not look like a regular form helper. (from regular documentation and unless it is kind of a custom method)

Comment: I'm using simple_form and this is how they do hidden inputs